# How to sort files by modified date in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I used NSFileManager to retrieve the files in a folder, and I want to sort them by modified date. How to do that ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

What have you tried so far?

I haven't done this, but a quick look at the docs makes me think that you should try the following:

1. Call `-contentsOfDirectoryAtURL:includingPropertiesForKeys:options:error:` and specify `NSURLContentModificationDateKey` as one of the keys.
2. You'll get back an array of NSURL objects which you can then sort using an NSArray method like `-sortedArrayUsingComparator:`.
3. Pass in a comparator block that looks up the modification date for each NSURL using `-getResourceValue:forKey:error:`.

**Update:** When I wrote the answer above, `-getResourceValue:forKey:error:` existed in iOS but didn't do anything. That method is now functional as of iOS 5. The following code will log an app's resource files followed by a list of corresponding modification dates:

```
NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *files = [manager contentsOfDirectoryAtURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourceURL]
                        includingPropertiesForKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSURLContentModificationDateKey]
                                           options:nil
                                             error:nil];
NSMutableArray *dates = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSURL *f in files) {
    NSDate *d = nil;
    if ([f getResourceValue:&d forKey:NSURLContentModificationDateKey error:nil]) {
        [dates addObject:d];
    }
}
NSLog(@"Files: %@", files);
NSLog(@"Dates: %@", dates);
```

Comment: Strangely, the docs for getResourceValue:forKey:error: say "This method is unimplemented in iOS, so it performs no operation."

Just below it, they say "Available in iOS 4.0 and later."

Why they would add a method that is unimplemented is confusing.  ?=|

More: http://www.themusingsofalostprogrammer.com/2011/06/what-were-they-thinking-apple.html

Comment: The Foundation framework is common to MacOS X and iOS, so it may be there simply because it's useful in MacOS X. On the other hand, it might still be worth trying in the hope that the documentation is incorrect -- it does happen once in a while.

Comment: @Dustin, note that the docs now indicate that `getResourceValue:forKey:error:` is functional in iOS 5. I did a quick test and confirmed that it works. I'll update the answer above as well.

Comment: Cool.  Do we know if internally it's optimized to just get those values from the file?  I get the feeling nothing in NSFileManager is optimized -- I recently learned even fileExists: loads EVERY attribute of the file.

Comment: @Dustin I have no idea how it's implemented or what it's optimized for. As it's usually a lot cheaper to access a file once and read all the data you might need than to access the same file several times, it wouldn't surprise me if all attributes are loaded at once. Looking at it pragmatically, you really shouldn't worry about it until you find that the behavior as implemented, whatever that is, is a bottleneck for your app.

Comment: Turns out it is as fast to read all the meta data as it is to check if a file exists on iOS, which explains fileExists.  It is a little annoying that it fills a NSDictionary with all the information.  I guess if you want to reduce that overhead you'll need to use stat.

Answer (score 2):

```
static static NSInteger contentsOfDirSort(NSString *left, NSString *right, void *ptr) {

    (void)ptr;

    struct stat finfo_l, r_finfo_r;

    if(-1 == stat([left UTF8String], &finfo_l))
        return NSOrderedSame;

    if(-1 == stat([right UTF8String], &finfo_r))
        return NSOrderedSame;

    if(finfo_l.st_mtime < finfo_r.st_mtime)
        return NSOrderedAscending;

    if(finfo_l.st_mtime > finfo_r.st_mtime)
        return NSOrderedDescending;

    return NSOrderedSame;
}
```

Now, later on in your code.

```
NSMutableArray *mary = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:filePathsArray];

[mary sortUsingFunction:contentsOfDirSort context:nil];

// Use mary...
```

Answer (score 2):

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray *imageFilenames = [manager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:nil];
    NSMutableArray *originalImage = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    for (int i = 1; i < [imageFilenames count]; i++)
    {
        NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",documentsDirectory,[imageFilenames objectAtIndex:i] ];

    }

    //---------sorting image by date modified
    NSArray*  filelist_date_sorted;

    filelist_date_sorted = [imageFilenames sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2)
                            {
                                NSDictionary* first_properties  = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory, obj1] error:nil];
                                NSDate *first = [first_properties  objectForKey:NSFileCreationDate];
                                NSDictionary *second_properties = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory, obj2] error:nil];
                                NSDate *second = [second_properties objectForKey:NSFileCreationDate];
                                return [second compare:first];
                            }];

NSLog(@" Date sorted result is %@",filelist_date_sorted);
```

Answer (score 0):

In a category over `NSFileManager`:

```
static  NSInteger contentsOfDirSort(NSURL *leftURL, NSURL *rightURL, void *ptr)
{
    (void)ptr;
    
    NSDate * dateLeft ;
    [leftURL getResourceValue:&dateLeft
                       forKey:NSURLContentModificationDateKey
                        error:nil] ;
    
    NSDate * dateRight ;
    [rightURL getResourceValue:&dateRight
                        forKey:NSURLContentModificationDateKey
                         error:nil] ;
    
    return [dateLeft compare:dateRight];
}




- (NSArray *)contentsOrderedByDateOfDirectoryAtPath:(NSURL *)URLOfFolder ;
{
    NSArray *files = [self contentsOfDirectoryAtURL:URLOfFolder
                         includingPropertiesForKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSURLContentModificationDateKey]
                                            options:0
                                              error:nil];
    
    return [files sortedArrayUsingFunction:contentsOfDirSort
                                   context:nil] ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick Method:

```
-(void)dateModified
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray *fileList = [manager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:nil];

    //--- Listing file by name sort
    NSLog(@"\n File list %@",fileList);




    int num;
    //-- Listing file name with modified dated
    for (NSString *s in fileList)
    {
        NSString *filestring = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingFormat:@"/%@",s];

        NSDictionary *filePathsArray1 = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:filestring error:nil];
        NSString *modifiedDate = [filePathsArray1 objectForKey:NSFileModificationDate];
        NSLog(@"\n Modified Day : %@", modifiedDate);

        num=num+1;
    }
}
```